# Order of assignment operation Java

Tags: java

The exercise reads as :
Exercise 32: The sum of a set of numbers

**Create a program that calculates the sum 1+2+3+…+n where n is a number entered by the user.**

Here's a part of working code:

```
int first = 1;
int sum = 0;

while (first <= read) {

        sum = sum + first;
        first++;

    }
```

Changing above to below:

```
int first = 1;
int sum = 0;

while (first <= read) {

        first++;
        sum = sum + first;

 }
```

Produces wrong answers.If read=3 then sum=9 instead of 6, if read=7 then sum=35 instead of 28 and so on.Why is that?

Comment: I suggest you debug through and see what happens. It should be much more helpful to you than someone telling you.

Comment: Try putting some print statements into your loop. Or better: you a pen and a piece of paper and *run* that thing yourself - without a computer. That is how you learn to solve such problems - not by dropping something that *only* requires a bit of energy to solve ... to others.

Comment: The difference between "increment first and then add it to sum" and "add first to sum and then increment it" seems obvious.

Comment: Analyze the loop and see for yourself, that you'll get: in 1-st loop 0 + 1 == 1, in 2-nd loop 1 + 1 == 2 (and there should have been + 2 at that point) and in 3-rd loop there's 2 + 1 == 3. So you basically count loop executions. It should be sum **+=** sum + 1.

Comment: What makes you think changing the order of operations produces the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second snippet you increment `first` before adding it to `sum`, which means you are calculating the sum

```
2 + 3 + ... + read + (read+1)
```

instead of

```
1 + 2 +  .......   + read.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. use a debugger to step through the code. This will give you insight into how to debug your code, teach you about how to use debugging tools, and it will easily help you spot the error.
2. You can avoid the (computationally) expensive loop.
   The direct formula for the sum of the first N numbers is (N * (N + 1)) / 2

Comment: While that's a helpful formula I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer to the actual question. It would probably better be a comment.

Comment: Gauss knew that when he was a teenager. ;-)